# What does "Start Turtlebot" button do?

Tags: ros, turtlebot2, turtlebot, groovy-turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just started working on Turtlebot2. I find a ros-turtle button on top (in the turtlebot laptop) which says 'start turtlebot'. What does it do exactly ? When I click, it changes to 'starting turtlebot'. The list of topics before and after starting are the same. So, what exactly is happening ? and also, will the status change to 'started turtlebot' ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56733/what-does-%22start-turtlebot%22-button-do-?/) by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1363 on 2013-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It starts turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch as user name 'ros'

It is just providing a easy way to start and stop turtlebot for non-ros developer who does not know how to play with console. So if you click it when turtlebot has not started, it will start Turtlebot automatically for you.

For more information, refer to the links below. and also turtlebot sig.

https://github.com/TurtleBot-Mfg/turtlebot-indicator-groovy

https://github.com/TurtleBot-Mfg/ros-system-daemon-groovy

---

Originally posted by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) with karma: 634 on 2013-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) on 2013-03-03**:
Thanks! But I don't think it works. I am not even able to tele-op the TurtleBot after that. The list of topics before and after the start are the same. What about that ?

**Comment by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on 2013-03-04**:
I am not sure what version of turtlebot-indicator you are using. The up-to-date version which is in [https://launchpad.net/~iheartengineering/+archive/ros-support](https://launchpad.net/%7Eiheartengineering/+archive/ros-support)

**Comment by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on 2013-03-04**:
should work fine. If you find any further problem regarding this. You can create an issue in https://github.com/turtlebot-mfg/turtlebot-indicator here